# Find the minimum possible value of $|A \cap B\cap C|$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

For any set $S$,  $|S|$ denotes the no. of elements of $S$ ; $n(S)$ denotes the no.of subsets of $S$ incl. the empty set and set $S$ itself

For $3$ sets, $A,B,C$ :-$$n(A)+n(B)+n(C)=n(A\cup B \cup C)$$
$$|A|=|B|=100$$

Find the minimum possible value of $|A \cap B\cap C|$

I know of two formulas:-

1. $n(S)=2^{|S|}$
2. $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|C\cap A|+|A \cap B\cap C|$

But then how can I use them??(This question is from the exercise of a combinatorics chapter)

Comment: Hint |C|=101.....

Comment: Hint: In $n(A)+n(B)+n(C)=n(A\cup B \cup C)$, the right-hand side is a power of $2$, and the left-hand side is the sum of three powers of $2$, two of which you already know.

Comment: @user35508 $|C|=101$ and $|A\cup B\cup C|=102$ But how to get $|A\cap B\cap C|$?? The facts do not seem to be enough!

Comment: Write |A Intersect B|=|A|+B|-|A union B|

Comment: @user35508 And how will I get $|A \cup B|$?

Comment: Hint :You have to minimize the sum...how would you do it

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints. The given information shows that
$$2^{100} + 2^{100} + 2^{|C|} = 2^{|A \cup B \cup C|}$$
In particular, $|C|$ must be such that the value on the left is a power of $2$, and as such, there is only one value $|C|$ can take. This also determines the value of $|A \cup B \cup C|$. I leave the rest to you...

Comment: $|C|=101$ and $|A\cup B\cup C|=102$ But how to get $|A\cap B\cap C|$?? The facts do not seem to be enough!

Comment: @sayan: The facts aren't enough to determine $|A \cap B \cap C|$, but you're not asked to determine $|A \cap B \cap C|$, you're asked to find its least possible value. I think using the formula for $|A \cup B \cup C|$ might not be the best idea here; try considering small values of $|A \cap B \cap C|$ and seeing if they're possible given the constraints.